# Credentials for Google Play Developer API

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api

I'm trying to access to [Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/).

For now, I've just downloaded the [sample projects](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/libraries), but I need a **Client ID** and a **Secret**. I've successfully created a service account from Google Play Console / Google API Console, but I don't know where to find these credentials. I'm supposed to include these credentials in a JSON file read by the code in the sample project.

Answer (score 0):

The [guide to doing this is here](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization).

You've already created the linked project. So you just need these steps:

- Go to API Access in the left-hand navigation panel.
- Select Create an OAuth 2.0 client ID.
- On the first page, you will need to fill in the product name, but a logo is not required. Note that your end users will not see the product name.
- On the second page, select web application and set the redirect URI and Javascript origins. Both of these settings can be changed later.
- Select Create client ID.